# Windows 7 elevated privilege window not appearing

Tags: windows-7, uac, privileges, steam

I have identified a very big problem that I have seen referenced by other posts in some programs, but usually work-arounded.

It is as simple as you trying to execute an application you have configured to be executed with elevated privileges, eg. [Counter Strike GO (with Steam)](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/846940248805016282/), and the application doesn't get run with them (I think neither booted) which makes unbootable the game.

Other times, it shows itself as when you try to execute a downloaded program, that doesn't get it's [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) auth window properly.

So, anyone knows about any way to solve (that not workaround) this? It was working alright before...

EDIT 1: Disabling completelly UAC to no-security (level 0) solves the problem, but I am trying to solve it, not to make a workaround

EDIT 2: ESET Smart Security (firewall and more) installed

Comment: run a `sfc /scannow` from the install dvd. tell us if the problem is gone.

Comment: When the UAC window doesn't appear as expected, does the Consent.exe process show up in the Task Manager at all?

Comment: prompt to run a Downloaded program != UAC

Comment: @techie007 no it doesn't. I will answer you all when I get back from work.

Comment: @surfasb If you mean to run a downloaded program that doesn't require UAC, it works. Anyway, this only happens sometimes. In my case, with TeamViewer